# Multithreaded EXE not spawning all of its threads when ran using child_process spawn

Tags: c++, node.js, electron

I have an electron app, and from it i am calling a multithreaded exe (written in c++) using spawn. But, instead of launching 8 threads and using all of my cpu cores, it runs on a single core. How could i change or allow the nodejs thread pool to be extended to let my exe spawn all of its threads? without using asynchronous c++ addons

Executing this using spawn outputs 8 (the number of threads on my system)

```
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** all of this had nothing to do with my nodejs. My c++ program had a launch error. No threading issues.

Comment: Node.js has no influence on the amount of threads this external process will use, as you demonstrated. How/when does the external process decide to start threads? Is it possible there is simply not enough work for it?

Comment: Please add a [mre]